# Setup Cassandra DB in django using cqlengine but without using django-cassandra-engine

Tags: python, django, django-models, cassandra, cqlengine

I'm a Django beginner and have developed 1 app using mysql as primary DB, but in my next project I have to use Cassandra db using https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine but do not use https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine (which is a wrapper over cqlengine?).

I dont have any clue How do I start? I mean how and where should I create db connection and then create models in models.py file?

Should I create connection in **init**.py file?in views.py? what would be the most efficient way?

would be great(for future readers too) if someone provide a simple configuration and a model.

Answer (score 3):

The [twissandra](https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra) demo should be a good example of how to build an app using Cassandra and Django.

In this implementation there is no [models.py](https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra/blob/176ba836325ef35f7fce0cced8d2522c20d4ec52/users/models.py) and the connection is maintained in the file [cass.py](https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra/blob/176ba836325ef35f7fce0cced8d2522c20d4ec52/cass.py#L7-L8).

You'll see cass.py also hosts all the functions required to return data from the C* database and make objects which are used by the system. This is where you would swap out the api requests with your CqlEngine code.

I hope these resources get you pointed in the right direction

Comment: Thanks! but I'm looking for only cqlengine source and using models.py. e.g. `from cqlengine import connection` `connection.setup(['127.0.0.1:9160'])`
can you please provide a source for that.

Comment: Twissandra has long been a project that time forgot.  You can look over my answer for the appropriate CQLEngine response.  A good example project to take a look at is:  [Meat Bot by rustyrazorblade, creator of CQLEngine](https://github.com/rustyrazorblade/meatbot/)

Answer (score 0):

[Rustyrazorblade](https://github.com/rustyrazorblade) shows an easy way to accomplish this via his CQLEngine tutorial branch [HERE](https://github.com/cqlengine/tutorial).

You can easily setup the connection by doing something like this in your_app_project/models/connection.py:

```
from cqlengine import management
from cqlengine.connection import setup

def connect():
    setup(["127.0.0.1", "127.0.1.1", "127.0.1.2"], "tutorial", retry_connect=True)
    management.create_keyspace("tutorial", replication_factor=1, strategy_class="SimpleStrategy")
```

In this example: "tutorial" is the **keyspace** we are using, **strategy_class** is the replication strategy your C* instance is using, **replication_factor** is the amount of replications that will be stored throughout the **ring**, **127.0.0.1** is a Cassandra cluster node IP address (you can pass this a list or a string) and **retry_connect** specifies whether or not you would like it to attempt to reconnect if there is a connection failure.

From here, it is very easy for new C* users to get confused.  You can call this anytime Before syncing the C* tables or using a C* query.

So, you'll want to do something like:

```
from cqlengine.management import sync_table
from models.connection import connect
from models.somemodels import MyCassandraModel

# This will fire off our previously setup 'connect' method
connect()
# This will setup the Model as a table in your C* DB
sync_table(MyCassandraModel)
```

You can even drop this into manage.py, just as long as that CQLEngine setup() is properly executed.